# Retrieve/Passing date and option data to databse via Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, date

I have problems dealing with ajax, couldn't pass the value from default form (`input type="data"`) together with option tag items

I've tried the datapicker ways to retrieve date, but the problems is i am not using datapicker, i'm using default PHP `input type="date"`. i wanna pass two value which are date and court_id to perform/display my table from database (right after two form had been clicked).

```
 /*this is display.php file*/
<input type="date" name="date_staff" id="staff_pick_date_ticket">

<select name='courtid' id='staff_select_court' multiple>
<option value='".$row['court_id']."'>".$row['courtTitle']."</option>
</select>

<div id="time_available">

/*this is myjs.php file*/
<script>  
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#staff_pick_date_ticket').click(function(){
    var date_id =$(this).data('staff_pick_date_ticket');
    $('#staff_select_court option').click(function() { 
        var court_id= $(this).attr('value'); 
        var action = 'show_time';
        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{date_id:date_id, court_id:court_id, action:action},
            success:function(data){
                $('#time_available').html(data);

              }
          })
      })
  })
  );  
</script>  

/*this is action.php file*/
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
if($_POST['action'] == 'show_time'){
$data = array(
    ':date_id' =>date("d/m/Y",strtotime($_POST["date_id"])),
    ':court_id'=>$_POST["court_id"]
    );
    echo $data[':date_id'];
    echo $data[':court_id'];
}
}
```

the court_id can be detected but the date_id is null. I don't know why? any solution here?

Comment: `':court_id'=>$_POST["courtid"]` use that

Comment: `$_POST["date_id"]` can you print this value and check what value you are reveiving

Comment: where is the value of `$_POST["court_id"]`?

Comment: @RameshN `$_POST["date_id"]` I tried it, there is no output showed, 
but `echo $data[':date_id'];` display _01/01/1970_ on my screen

Comment: @dean the display value of `echo $data[':court_id'];` is _20_, which is correct int value that retrieve from database before

Comment: @BelleluckLow, sorry, the problem is the date `name="date_staff"` that is the date value , so use `$_POST["date_staff"]`

Comment: @BelleluckLow check my answer, I think it will help you

Comment: @dean i know `$_POST["date_staff"]` is the date value, but if i wanna pass the value via ajax, aren't we need to use `id` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are not receiving date field value

Replace

```
var date_id =$(this).data('staff_pick_date_ticket');
```

with

```
var date_id =$('#staff_pick_date_ticket').val();
```

You will get the date value

Comment: i just tried this, but the output still the same which is `01/01/1970` (**default wrong date**) and  `20` (**correct court_id**) and `Unknown column 'date_id' in 'where clause'36`